# set parent class in child class java

Tags: java, parent-child

I have a method in my child class

```
public void setParent(Platform parent){

}
```

in which I need to set the parent class for the child class. How do you do this?

Comment: Is this an inner class? Is the child an object of the parent? What exactly do you mean?

Comment: You define the parent class when you declare the child class.

Comment: Yes the problem is I need to change the parent class within the child class which is declared to another parent class :/ its all really convoluted and if I did not need to do this for an assignment I would never even attempt it.

Comment: What do you mean by "parent"? What classes are you referring to? Are these JComponents, and you want to reparent a component to a different JPanel, for instance?

Comment: Please, can you post more code and information. If it's too many code, try to explain with a simple example with two classes (`Parent`, `Child`) and main with example of use or what did you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in Java there is [polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html). If its child class in sense it inherits from parent class you have inside your parent class `super` property which is reference to parent class.
You can invoke methods on it like `super.someParentMethod()` etc or call constructors like

```
public Child( argument ){ super(argument) }
```

If you have just logical structure in your application and not inherits child form parent class I believe your child's method is good however you need to assign parent class form itself, meaning in parent use

```
Child child = new Child();
child.setParent(this);
```

With this in child class you just assign parent to some parent variable and you can use it.

Not sure if that answers your question as you specified not enough details.

Comment: Pleasure. You should update your question with better explanation about situation you have so it is not down voted and also its more helpful to other users looking for similar problem.